# How does adding braces to a variable prevent it from being borrowed (owned?) by a match?

Tags: rust, scoping, borrowing

I'm trying to understand an [implementation of a binary tree in Rust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133209/binary-tree-implementation-in-rust/133776#133776) and I can't wrap my head around some scoping magic in the `locate_mut` function:

```
match {anchor} {
    &mut Some(ref mut node) if key != node.value.key() => {
        anchor = if key < node.value.key() {
            &mut node.left
        } else {
            &mut node.right
        }
    },
    other @ &mut Some(_) |
    other @ &mut None => return other
}
```

Comment: [Related blog post: "stuff the identity function does"](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/) (the linked list example is pretty similar to the binary tree code of yours). I hope Shepmaster answers your question ^_^

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt or that Matthieu M and oli_obk - ker have already answered it ;-)